# Difficult in converting to strings from a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list which is in below format

```py
A = [ "machine's code" ,"max's code"]
```

I want to convert to that list to string and pass it to a query. I am using python for this.

I am trying with below query and not giving required results

```py
for i in A:query=Select * from table where name='"+str(A)+"'"
```

Expected code should be :
`Select * from table where name="machine's code"`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski  Ratna asks to generate strings, nothing to do with a risk of SQL injection or other, your comments are out of context.

Comment: @ErnestBidouille: And that's how SQL injection attacks still occur in 2022. Someone asks a question about string interpolation or f-strings when they are clearly building a SQL query and no one bothers to educate them about the bad habit they just learned that will trip them up years later.

Answer (score -1):

```
list_of_queries = []
for element in A:
    query = f'Select * from table where name="{el}"'
list_of_queries.append(query)
```

as pointed out by others here, this pattern should be only used internally, as it creates some sql injection security risks.

Comment: No it has many elements

Comment: I need name in double quotes in the query

Comment: check the updated version now. An F-string works both ways, you can always switch the outer and inner quote characters.